# Send email to multiple recipients using win32com module in Python

Tags: python, email, win32com

I am using win32com to send emails after my code is done. However, I cannot figure out how to send it to more than 1 person. Now I can only add myself in cc, but not in the recipient list.

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
import datetime as date

olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = 'Hi'
newMail.Body = 'Hi'
newMail.To = 'Amy'
newMail.CC = 'Bob'    
newMail.Send()
```

However if I try this:

```
newMail.To = ['Amy','Bob']
```

An error occurs:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, u'Microsoft Office Outlook', u'Type Mismatch: Cannot coerce parameter value. Outlook cannot translate your string.', None, 0, -2147352571), 1)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try separating by semicolons:

```
newMail.To = 'Amy; john; sandy'
```

If you do a web search for "outlook interop createitem" you can find the docs for `MailItem.To` where this is explained.

Update: this is not an Outlook script, it is a Python script that uses Python's win32com module to control Outlook. The docs I'm referring to are the VB/C# docs for Outlook's COM interface ([for example the possible values of OlItemType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olitemtype%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks I actually dont know whats going on inside this module, and I havent written outlook scripts before. Is MailItem.To a built in function in Outlook? If so, I think for most problems I can just go for Outlook Docs.

Comment: @Twinkle If this worked please accept answer so we know this resolved issue. I will clarify answer.

Comment: If you want it it be more dynamic then you should try the following:
newMail.To = ";".join([i for i in to if isinstance(to, list) == True]).

Comment: How to add a specific sender name if required?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list to a string, make sure you add the ';' at the end of each recipient:

```
newMail.To = "".join(<your_list>)
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `newMail.To = ";".join(<your_list>)` (including the semicolon in the join statement)